# My ubuntu stuck on splash screen

Tags: drivers, screen, plymouth, gpu-driver

My ubuntu stuck on splash screen and showing white cursors and not booting this problem occurred when i upgrade my distro
My laptop..
Asus xl540la
Intel i3 with integrated hd5500 graphics

Comment: While on splash screen, Press "Down arrow" key. You can see a full screen terminal kind of window and see what's going on, by log messages. If you see any error message in the end or within a page, tell us what it is by updating your question.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen because of Drivers

which Version of Ubuntu are you using ?  which one you were before ?

if "Ubuntu Logo" goes off and the mouse cursor keeps "appearing disapearing" (it means it already booted!)
 **if you want to reinstall ubuntu , but keep all the data**
Press *CTRL + Alt + F3* . Now you are in Shell mode, you can Login and 
**this will reinstall ubuntu without losing data**

> sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop

If it doesnt go past the Loading Logo , you will need a Live ubuntu image to enter in terminal.

Please post more info about the issue